# Selenium Webdriver / JUnit how to find an element that isn't there when the page loads but get's added by a script after a button is clicked?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

Selenium Webdriver / JUnit how to find an element that isn't there when the page loads but get's added by a script after a button is clicked?

The page's source looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

   function showResult(value)
   {
       document.getElementById(result).innerHTML= "5"; 
   }
   </script>

</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1> Simple Calculator </h1>
<form action="/~path/math1.php" method="post">
Number One: <input type="text" name="num1" />
Number Two: <input type="text" name="num2" />
....
```

Then after a submit button is clicked the page's source looks like this:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

   function showResult(value)
   {
       document.getElementById(result).innerHTML= "5"; 
   }

   </script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1> Simple Calculator </h1>
Result :<input type="text" name="result" value=25 /><form     action="/~path/math1.php" method="post">
Number One: <input type="text" name="num1" />
Numbre Two: <input type="text" name="num2" />
....
```

I want to get the 'result' after submit is clicked to use in a JUnit assertion test.

```
WebElement result = driver.findElement(By.name("result"));
assertEquals(result, 25);
```

Doesn't work though. I think this is because the result element is not initially there. How can I find it after submit has been clicked? 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Put in an explicit wait to check for visibility of the result input box with webdriverwait and ExpectedConditions

Comment: you can also use [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) which takes care of dynamic elements. It also provides assertion and verification methods with element. For instance:

   WebElement ele = new QAFExtendedWebElement(By.name(''result");
   ele.verifyValue("25");

If you are starting from scratch you can walk through [step-by-step tutorial](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki)